# Proper way to make Nested RxJS HATEOAS request? - StackBlitz Included

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, stackblitz

First of all, I've already reviewed similar questions but still I'm a bit confused.

I'm working with [OGCSensorThings](https://developers.sensorup.com/docs/#introduction), that API Standard makes use of HATEOAS therefore the nested information is formed as URI.

I must display each thing information as a component for each of them, that's not difficult if I have the complete object, but I'm having problems to map each thing with its related Data in a single OGC Sensorthing Object.

By now I've successfully retrieved Things and Datastreams but I'm stuck wondering how to relate those Datastreams with its respective Things as there is no specific relation in the retrieved object but the URI pointing to the information.

That's my actual approach to retrieve Things and Datastreams: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gcktjt?file=src/app/hello.component.ts)

```
    public obs$ = zip(this.obs1$).pipe(
    map((things) => {
      console.log('Things: ', el);
      return this.getDatastreamURLsAndSetThingsToMap(things);
    }),
    concatMap((datastreamURLArray) => {
      const datastreamObservableHttpRequests =
        this.getHttpObs<Datastream[]>(datastreamURLArray);
      return zip(datastreamObservableHttpRequests).pipe(
        tap((el) => console.log('datastream', el))
      );
    })
  );
```

Is there any proper way with RxJS to return a formed object containing all the retrieved information? (This should include Thing{ [{Datastream[{Sensor{},ObservedProperty{}}]]}) Again, the tricky part is to relate the tables as they have no Foreign Keys, they have URIs. *Maybe I'm doing this in a complete wrong way, if so, please bring me some light*

Observations, Locations, HistoricalLocation are non-static values so once the Thing Object/OGCObject is built I should use an interval to update those values and be able to see changes in screen, by location or observation last value.

See the OGC UML diagram:
[image: OGC UML diagram]

Comment: What is your actually your problem ? Your code looks fine to me.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Hi Thank you for your reading time, the actual problem is to link those first retrieved Things with its related Datastreams and same with sensors and observatedProperties for those Datastreams. Since they have no Foreign Keys relating  them.